# Running a vbs script from batch with admin rights doesn't work

Tags: session, vbscript

I will execute a vb script (script1) from an batch which runs with administrator rights (Windows 7).
When I execute the VBS script without administrator privileges it works fine, but with administrator rights nothing happens.

I thought of a user session "problem" but when I check the sessions with `qprocess` or with the Windows task manager both (outlook and the script) runs in session 1.

But it must have to do with sessions because when I test it with a second script (script2) I get a "jap" when I start the vbs from a "normal" cmd and a "nope" when the cmd has administrator rights.

So has anyone an idea what the problem is here?

script1:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim oOL
Set oOL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Dim olkIns


If oOL Is Nothing Then
    'Outlook is not running
Else
    'Outlook running
    oOL.Application.ActiveExplorer.Activate 
    WScript.Sleep 1000

    Shell.AppActivate("Outlook") 
    Do while oOL.Inspectors.Count <> 0
        For each olkIns in oOl.Inspectors
                olkIns.Close olSave
            Next
    Loop

    oOL.Session.Logoff
    oOL.Quit
End If
Set oOL = Nothing
```

script2:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim oOL
Set oOL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Dim olkIns


If oOL Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "nope"
Else
    MsgBox "jap"
End If
Set oOL = Nothing
```

Comment: It has probably something to do with the security tokens and integrity levels of the outlook.exe running without UAC and the cmd running with UAC. Did you try if it works if you do not get the object but create it?

Comment: Does your current user have admin rights, or do you have a second user account with admin privileges?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers
Its the current user - no "runas" - only get administrator rights through UAC.

Comment: @Syberdoor
Yes I test it also with "CreateObject" - without success.

Comment: Looks like you can't attach a process/object without admin privileges from an administrative process. I suspect this is for security reasons, to avoid prvilege escalation.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers
Yes I also think its not working for securtiy reasons, even it would make more sense if it were the other way round.
I will look for another solution or start the script with an scheduler task.
Not the nicest workaround but it works.

Comment: Anyone else with an idea? 
Otherwise I will use the workaround with a scheduler task.